# Facebook graph API to retrieve messages sent to/from a friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, filter, facebook-messages

Facebook graph API allows to retrieve chat messages using "GET /me/outbox". Is there any way to retrieve the messages sent to/from a friend using graph API modifiers rather than parsing the entire array of messages.

Comment: I am looking for something like GET /me/outbox?from=<name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fql, just change the FRIEND_USER_ID:

```
SELECT author_id, body, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 1 AND 'FRIEND_USER_ID' IN (recipients))
```

You can test with graph API explorer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the thread_id, or the facebook thread id, then yes. Use /me/inbox or /me/outbox and select a specific id graph.facebook.com/messageid

Comment: I am trying to display the message exchange between a friend and me. I do not want to pull the entire list messages to show messages with just one friend. looking for something like GET /me/outbox?from=<name>